# Android animation on textview

Tags: android, animation

I want to do an infinite animation on my textview. But it doesnt work! This is my animation xml

```
<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

<alpha
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

and this is my code in my activity

```
void animation(){

    Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.animationtext);
    tviPrueba.startAnimation(anim1);
    anim1.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

}
```

Comment: you probably need to set the `setRepeatCount()` before setting the animation to the TextView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't complicate yourself... if is infinite, use the reverse mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000" 
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite" />
</set>
```

remove the `anim1.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);` line and use my xml

Comment: no problem :) remember to accept my answer so everyone can find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.animationtext);
anim1.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
tviPrueba.startAnimation(anim1);
```